# Convert Pandas column of List values to headers with counts

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to reshape the dataset `df` below to show the `values` lists as column headers and the frequency they appear as the value (desired output shown at bottom). TBH I'm a little stumped as how to move forward; like should I make a dataframe with the appropriate rows and columns and then attempt to populate via a lambda function?

```
keys = ["panda1", "panda2", "panda3"]

values = [["eats", "shoots"], ["shoots", "leaves"], ["eats", "leaves"]]

df = pd.DataFrame({"keys": keys, "values": values})    
df

     keys            values
0  panda1    [eats, shoots]
1  panda2  [shoots, leaves]
2  panda3    [eats, leaves]
```

Does anyone have any guidance on the best ways to move forward? Not necessarily code examples just logic of what needs to happen next.

Desired output:

```
     keys            eats         shoots        leaves    total
0  panda1              1            1             0         2
1  panda2              0            1             1         2
2  panda3              1            0             1         2
```

Comment: Your desired output is called a [***crosstabulation***](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) of the counts for each (individual) string (column names), and key value (row index). And as to the input column being a list of string, the intermediate step is to [***explode***](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the `values` column so that each individual row with a list becomes multiple rows with individual strings. This the pandas terminology for what you want to do; makes it easier to find answers.

Comment: ...and specifically you want a crosstab with ***row margins*** (i.e. subtotals)

Answer (score 2):

Try [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) + [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab) with Margins + [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas-dataframe-iloc) to strip off bottom margin:

```
new_df = df.explode('values')
new_df = (
    pd.crosstab(new_df['keys'], new_df['values'],
                margins=True, margins_name='Total')
        .iloc[:-1]
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index()
)
```

`new_df`:

```
     keys  eats  leaves  shoots  Total
0  panda1     1       0       1      2
1  panda2     0       1       1      2
2  panda3     1       1       0      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

```
df.join(df['values'].str.join(',')
        .str.get_dummies(sep=',')
        .assign(total = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)))
```

Comment: Yes. I guess `.assign(total = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))` is less grief than `pd.crosstab(..., margins=True, margins_name='Total')` then cleaning that up with `.iloc[:-1]` and `.reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

Could make code shorter but readability is important

`explode` to open up list

```
df2=df.apply(lambda x: x.explode())
```

`get_dummies` to pivot the value entities as word count if you like and sum them up column wise

```
 df3=df.join(pd.get_dummies(df2['values'], dummy_na=False).sum(level=0))
```

Sum up the word count rowwise. `.iloc` accessor helps you eliminate the non numerical fields by slicing columns

```
df3=df3.assign(Total=df3.iloc[:,2:].sum(1))



   keys        values        eats  leaves  shoots  Total
0  panda1    [eats, shoots]     1       0       1      2
1  panda2  [shoots, leaves]     0       1       1      2
2  panda3    [eats, leaves]     1       1       0      2
```

Comment: Remember to include a short description about your code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_dummies` and `explode` to get the value counts, then to create the total by using `sum`.

```
(
    pd.get_dummies(df.explode('values'), columns=['values'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
    .groupby('keys').sum()
    .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(total= x.sum(axis=1)))
    .reset_index()
)


    keys    eats    leaves  shoots  total
0   panda1  1       0       1       2
1   panda2  0       1       1       2
2   panda3  1       1       0       2
```